# ExtJS4, add row of combobox and other fields to panel - combobox list issue

Tags: forms, combobox, extjs4, row, addition

first thanks to everyone for their contributions/assistance to these forums. I've searched online for days and I can't /find a solution to/figure out what's wrong.
I have a form panel, which initially has a single row (container using hbox layout) of a set of fields (comboboxes, textfields, buttons, etc) which a user can use to build boolean statement. This container also has buttons for 'AND', 'OR' and 'DEL' which can be used for appending another row (boolean statement) or deleting the current row to the form panel. I have local stores for the combobox values and this works all works fine/good...sort of.
My problem is after a user has typed in a value into any of the comboboxes and when they add a new row, the combobox list of the new row is limited to what was chosen in the prior row - and only that value.
I can see that the store of the new row's combobox has all the right values via firebug, but these aren't accessible through the GUI. I thought it was a browser issue, but can't shake it in Ffox nor IE. It's never a problem if they only select via the mouse. I've tried stripping down the combobox config, etc, searching online, using a fieldset instead of container. Any thoughts/ideas?

```
Ext.define('SearchTool.view.main.component.QueryBuilderRow', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.builderRow',
requires: ['SearchTool.config.Config'],
layout: 'hbox',
items: [{
    xtype: 'combo',
    cls: 'cboxFields',
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['fieldname', 'fieldvalue'],
        data: [
            ['field1', 'FIELD1'],
            ['field2', 'FIELD2'],
            ['field3', 'FIELD3'],
            ['field4', 'FIELD4']
        ]
    }),
    editable: true,
    selectOnFocus: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    displayField: 'fieldname',
    valueField: 'fieldvalue',
    emptyText: '(Select Field)',
    typeAhead: true,
    value: '',
    triggerAction: 'query',
    queryMode: 'local',
    width: '15%'
    }, {
    xtype: 'combo',
    cls: 'cboxOpers',
    store: operStore,
    displayField: 'opername',
    valueField: 'opervalue',
    emptyText: '(Select Oper)',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'query',
    shrinkWrap: 1,
    selectOnFocus: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    width: '15%',
    enableKeyEvents: true
    }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    // itemId: 'val1',
    width: '18%',
    emptyText: '(Enter value...)',
    regex: SearchTool.config.Config.qryBuilderTextFieldRegex,
    regexText: SearchTool.config.Config.qryBuilderErrText,
    enableKeyEvents: true
    }, {
    xtype: 'combo',
    cls: 'cboxAndOr',
    store: andorStore,
    minChars: 1,
    disabled: true,
    displayField: 'opername',
    valueField: 'opervalue',
    typeAhead: true,
    emptyText: '(AND/OR)',
    allowBlank: true,
    enforceMaxLength: true,
    matchFieldWidth: true,
    mode: 'local',
    width: '12%'
    }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    width: '17%',
    emptyText: '(Enter value...)'
    }, {
    xtype: 'hidden',
    value: ''
    }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    iconCls: 'icon-btnAdd',
    text: 'AND',
    width: '7%',
    handler: function (t) {
    t.up('panel').add({xtype:'builderRow'}); //add new row
    t.up('panel').items.items[t.up('panel').items.items.length -                     
        2].down('button').next('button').next('button').hide();
    t.prev('hidden').setValue(' AND '); //to be passed in w/ form
    }
    }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    iconCls: 'icon-btnAdd',
    text: 'OR',
    width: '6.5%',
    handler: function (t) {
    t.up('panel').add({xtype:'builderRow'}); //add new row
    t.up('panel').items.items[t.up('panel').items.items.length - 2].down('button').next('button').next('button').hide();
    t.prev('hidden').setValue(' OR ');
    }
    }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    iconCls: 'icon-btnDelete',
    text: 'DEL',
    width: '7%',
    handler: function (t, e, o) {
    var i = t.up('panel').items.items;
    var l = i.length; //length of the array of items
    if (l > 2) i[l - 2].down('button').next('button').next('button').show();
    i[t.up('panel').items.items.length - 2].down('hidden').setValue(''); //prev row hidden reset

    t.up('panel').remove(t.up('container')); //remove this row
    }
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reuse stores for the different combo boxes. Create new store for every combo of every row. This is because, when you type, you're filtering the data on the combo box. The data is contained within the store, so you're basically filtering the store, which is shared among the combos.

So once you filter for row 1, the filter remains active for row 2. If a new store is used for every combo, the problem will not arise.